# Only show region title for players entering/exiting the area in Bedrock edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've added a creative region to my survival world and when players enter/exit that region, I want to display a title and subtitle like so:

[image: Home base title displayed.]

This is easy enough to do with the `title` command and a **command block**, but I'm having trouble getting the title to only display for players entering/exiting the area.

Currently, I'm trying to chain **command block**s to accomplish this task, but I'm not against crafting a function for it, as that's the end goal anyways (*though I need the command block way first because my behavior pack isn't ready yet*). The setup is currently:

```
# Block 1 (Repeat, Unconditional, Always Active)
tag @a[r=64] add "home"

# Block 2 (Chain, Conditional, Always Active)
gamemode creative @a[r=70,tag="home"]

# Block 3 (Chain, Conditional, Always Active)
tag @a[r=70,tag="home"] add "home-title"

# Block 4 (Chain, Conditional, Always Active)
title @a[r=70,tag="home-title"] subtitle "This is a safe space."

# Block 5 (Chain, Conditional, Always Active)
title @a[r=70,tag="home-title"] title "Home Base"
```

There are three other **command block**s that are responsible for the exit process, all of which are set to:

- Repeat
- Unconditional
- Always Active

Their commands are:

```
# Block 1
tag @a[rm=65] remove "home"

# Block 2
tag @a[rm=65] remove "home-title"

# Block 3
gamemode survival @a[rm=65]
```

My thought process was that for players that already have the **home** tag, the remaining blocks wouldn't execute, however this is not a true statement, and in hindsight, it never could've been since all remaining blocks impact all players within a 64 block radius.

---

How can I adjust my setup to ensure only players that are entering/exiting the area will see the title/subtitle with **command block**s?

<sub>*Bonus: Can it be done in a single function?*</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Penguin's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/387125/274742) helped me arrive at the answer I needed so go upvote their answer!

---

I had a few issues with my setup. The first was that I was adding the `home-title` tag before displaying the title, so all users always had the `home-title` tag. Even with [@Penguin](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/258509/penguin)'s addition of the not operator `!` to my logic chain, all users were still seeing the title.

I had to change the order of command execution, in addition to adding the not operator in order for it to work:

```
#Block 1 (Repeat, Unconditional, Always Active)
tag @a[r=64,tag=!"home"] add "home"

#Block 2 (Chain, Conditional, Always Active)
gamemode creative @a[r=75,tag="home"]

#Block 3 (Chain, Conditional, Always Active)
title @a[r=75,tag=!"home-title"] subtitle "This is a safe space."

#Block 4 (Chain, Conditional, Always Active)
title @a[r=75,tag=!"home-title"] title "Home Base"

#Block 5 (Chain, Conditional, Always Active)
tag @a[r=75,tag="home"] add "home-title"
```

With this setup only the players entering the area will see the title, while the players already in the area won't.

Answer (score 2):

I am slightly confused as to what you're asking, but I think your issue is that you don't want:

```
tag @a[r=64] add "home"
```

to return a success if they already have home. If so, simply replace this command with:

```
execute @a[r=64,tag=!home] tag @s add "home"
```

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I needed, but it helped me get there! I'll be awarding a bounty to your answer as soon as it's eligible!